# create a windows 8 task schedule for a vbscript using a script

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I have some payback at work i need to take care of. I have a fellow worker that has been the "funny man" for a few weeks now.

I have a background i know that will drive him nuts. I have limited time while he walks off to change his background to something i know he will get mad at.

I have made a vbscript that changes his background as soon as its executed on windows 8.

but want i wanted to do, is have it set a task schedule in windows 8 to auto run it every 30 minutes so if he changes it to something else it will auto change back again and drive him bonkers. I know i can manually set this but time is limited. So to be able to plant the files and execute a bash script that creates a task schedule to run that vbscript would be awesome.

The VBScript i have tested and working to change the background is below:

```
dim shell
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wallpaper = "C:\WINDOWS\system_logs\maxresdefault.jpg"
shell.RegWrite "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper", wallpaper
shell.Run "%windir%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters", 1, True
```

Comment: I like the way you think!

Comment: i ended up recording a text to speech wav file and it also plays every 15 minutes. it simply says a nick name he HATES. its been months now. it still does it, he just keeps his pc sound muted. hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove bash tag from your question !
You should use `schtasks`
Syntax :

> schtasks /create /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun /sc minute [/mo {1 - 1439}]
>   [/st StartTime] [/sd StartDate] [/ed EndDate] [/s computer [/u
>   [domain]user /p password]] [/ru {[Domain]User | "System"} [/rp
>   Password]]

```
schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 30 /tn "background changer" /tr c:\changer.vbs
```

Comment: Thank you  :)

Worked a treat. Now i wait.